# Efficient implementation (vectorized) in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a matrix in numpy

```
A = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6],
     [7,8,9]]
```

and a plain array

```
B = [2,1,0]
```

I want to compress the matrix into a single column such that for the ith row I want to pick the B[i]th column and put it in the column vector

So I want an elegant/vectorized implementation to get

```
Ans = [3,5,7]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [32]: A[np.arange(A.shape[0]), B]
Out[32]: array([3, 5, 7])
```

Comment: I tried to use index slicing instead of arange, something like A[:,B]/A[:,B[:]] ofcourse didnt work! This is elegant thanks!!

Comment: @Naman, glad it helps :)